# Arrays in JAVA , example of the smallest Value

Tags: java

Can you explain me how this works with an example/the steps?

```
public class MyClass {
    static void fors(int[] b) {
        for(int i = 0; i < b.length - 1; i++) {
            int o = b[i];
            int p = b[i + 1];
            if(o < p)
                b[i + 1] = o;
            if(i == b.length - 2)
                System.out.println(b[i + 1]);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int[] a = {2, 12, 42, 5, 9, 17, 20, 20, 3, 29, 80, 41, 1};
       fors(a);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Best explanation -- use a debugger and step through the code, seeing for yourself what it is doing at each step.

Comment: what do you think is happening?

Comment: It give us the smallest value ? Maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is replacing the next bigger value with the smaller current value. According to your code, the array would result like this: 
        a = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1};

If you wanna find the smallest value,

```
    //Assume the first one in the array the smallest first
    int smallest = b[0];

    //Then iterate the loop and compare the values
    for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        //if the value is smaller than the current smallest, then which is the smallest?
        if(b[i] < smallest) 
            smallest = b[i];
    }
```